# Communicate from ChildFragment to Parent when parent button's onClick

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel, android-navigation, fragmentmanager

I have a parent `Fragment` that has inside a `FragementContainerView` in which there is a transition of different Fragments. The parentFragment has a button that when is clicked it has to collect all the data from the different children fragments inside the container view. I am using `Navigation` component and `FragmentResultAPI`, the first for the fragment navigation/transition and the last for getting the results from the children to the parent. I know how to return back the data from the children to the parent, but I do not know how to notify the children to send the data back. I've found this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_fragment, container, false);
MyFirstChildFragment fragment = (MyFirstChildFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.child_fragment_id);
fragment.heyChildrenGiveMeYourDataBack(); //on Button click listener
```

I know this is the traditional way, but I was wondering there was a more modern way or, let's call it, a *Navigation way*.

The parent fragment belongs to the `main_graph_nav` but all children belong to a different `nested_graph_nav`. So I have a scoped `ViewModel` to share the data between the children but still no idea how to notice the children to send the data back to the parent.

Comment: Consider using an event bus.  https://greenrobot.org/eventbus/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally decided to search the FragmentManager of the parent in the child's code in order to set the Fragment result by calling:

```
getParentFragment().getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResult...
```

and inside the parent's code get the result by:

```
getChildFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener...
```

Comment: also have a look at my questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70721218/receive-fragment-result-in-navigation-component-fragment and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70680327/toolbar-icon-handling-using-navigation-component

Comment: your solutions works as there is another NavHost Fragment between parent and childFragment