# Receive fragment result in Navigation Component Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

> I have implemented NavHost(**Navigation Component**) in **MainFragment**(that contain `NavHost`) and it has three other fragment in it's nav (**CategoryFragment**,**GalleryFragment** and **PreviewFragment**)

Above three fragment are `sibliing` in `nav_graph`. I want to send a model to our parentFragment(**MainFragment**)

I have tried two different ways to send data to **parentFragment**(MainFragment)

**PreviewFragment.kt** on Button Click

```
parentFragmentManager.setFragmentResult("requestKey", bundleOf("bundleKey" to args.photo.imageUrl))
findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set("requestKey", args.photo.imageUrl)
```

**MainFragment.kt** 0nViewCreated

```
navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<String>("requestKey")?.observe(
            viewLifecycleOwner) { result ->
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "$result in MainFragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
childFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener("requestKey") { requestKey, bundle ->
            // We use a String here, but any type that can be put in a Bundle is supported
            val result = bundle.getString("bundleKey")
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "$result in MainFragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            // Do something with the result
        }
```

I have seen post that said FragmentManager should be same to handle fragment result api.

> I have tried it **parentFragmentManager** , **childFragmentManager** and directly.

Comment: Have you tried [safeArgs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data) for sending data?.. [Here are the supported types](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#supported_argument_types)

Answer (score 2):

You can try these:

```
requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.setFragmentResult
requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener
```

Comment: I know this answer didn't answer the current question. But it answered my scenario where the listener was not getting any results when I try to communicate from fragment to an activity. In the fragment, I was using just `setFragmentResult` to send the result and it didn't work. But when I used `requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.setFragmentResult`, it worked all of a sudden. I've no idea why this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

As there is another Fragment(NavHostFragment) between childFragment and ParentFragment in Navigation Component. I have found [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68532133/4134215)
In ChildFragment you have to call

```
parentFragment?.parentFragmentManager?.setFragmentResult
```

And in ParentFragment(that has NavHost)

```
childFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener
```